# display problem of glmtree with terminal_panel node_bivplot or node_barplot

Tags: r, decision-tree

I use different decision trees applying to the same data but most of them can display like the following figure

[image: see here].

When I use `glmtree`, there is an error at terminal nodes

> Error in `[.data.frame`(X, , which, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns
>   selected

```
columncol<-hcl(c(250,10), 200, 60, 1)
labelcol<-hcl(265, 150, 100, 0.9)
indexcol<-hcl(270, 65, 65, 0.9)
#png(file='c:/glmtree-exmaple.png', width = 1024, height = 512)
plot(glm.model, drop_terminal = TRUE,
      inner_panel = node_inner(glm.model, fill = c(labelcol, indexcol)),
      terminal_panel=node_bivplot(glm.model, pointcol = "black", boxcol = "black", boxfill = "lightgray", bg = "white", cdplot = FALSE), main="glmtree")
#dev.off()
```

where glm.model is my result obtained from `glmtre`e function.

If I delete the `terminal_panel` part, it works. But the information of terminal nodes is important, I was wondering if there is any solution that can display the terminal nodes in `glmtree` by colourfull boxplot?